# Битрикс24 - распределение лидов согласно посменному графику

Tags: rest, битрикс24

В Битрикс24 настроен учет рабочего времени через посменный график. Заливаю лиды через REST API и вижу, что лиды разлеглись поровну между всеми сотрудниками без учета того, кто работает сегодня или завтра на смене, а кто нет.

Ну ничего, думаю, я сам поставлю ответственного при заливке лидов, мне бы только расписание скачать. Заглядываю в доку по REST API и не могу найти методов, чтобы скачать расписание смен.

Кто-нибудь знает, есть ли такой метод в REST API и можно ли решить задачу иным способом?